# Extension of an additive function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set, $S\subset \mathcal P(X)$ such that:

$1) X\in S$,
$2) A,B\in S, A\cap B=\emptyset \Rightarrow A\sqcup B\in S$ and
$3) A,B\in S, A\subset B \Rightarrow B\setminus A \in S$

Moreover we have a function $f: S\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that

$ A,B\in S, A\cap B=\emptyset \Rightarrow f(A\sqcup B)=f(A)+f(B) $  and
$f(X)=1$

I wonder if it is possible to extend domain of $f$ so it remains additive. Every extension theorem I've found start with function defined on ring or algebra so I can't use that.

Comment: Is $\sqcup$ supposed to represent union?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Most likely it represents disjoint union.

Comment: @Math1000 wouldn't disjoint be implied since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: In that case they are the same.

Comment: To where would you like to extend $f$?  To entire $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: Yes, $\sqcup$ stands for union with assumption that $A,B$ are disjoint.
Eventually, yes, but extension to some ring of sets containing S (family closed under sums and relative complements) would suffice since i can then use Caratheodory extension theorem (i'd like to use this in situation where smallest sigma-algebra containing $S$ is $\mathcal P(X)$)

Comment: What is missing from your scheme that makes it possible that $S$ is not a semiring? (I'm a bit out of practice on these issues.)

Comment: I don't have assumption that $S$ is stable under intersections. (And since it's stable only under taking disjoint sum i can't use de'Morgan laws to show that)

Comment: If someone is interested following condition is sufficient:
$\{A_n, B_m | n\in\{1,\dots,N\}, m\in\{1,\dots,M\}\}\subset S$ such that $\sum_n \chi_{A_n}=\sum_m \chi_{B_m}$ implies $\sum_n f(A_n)=\sum_m f(B_m)$

It's proven in "Theory of Charges_ A Study of Finitely Additive Measures" by K.P.S Bhaskara Rao and M. Bhaskara Rao